# Override Price Template Magento local.xml

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to modify the price.phtml templates based on whether or not the customer is logged in.  I'm attempting to use local.xml inside the customer_logged_out handle.

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>grouped</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>configurable</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>virtual</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>msrp</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>msrp_item</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>msrp_noform</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

While this isn't setting my desired template, I do know that it is having an effect.  I've added the following debug information to

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Price/Template.php

    public function addPriceBlockType($type, $block = '', $template = '')
    {
        Mage::log('Type: ' . $type . ', Block: ' . $block . ', Template: ' . $template, null, 'priceblock.log');
        if ($type) {
            $this->_priceBlockTypes[$type] = array(
                'block'     => $block,
                'template'  => $template
            );
        }

        Mage::log($this->_priceBlockTypes, null, 'priceblock.log');
        return $this;
    }
```

This yields the following output:

```
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: msrp, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/price_msrp.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: msrp_item, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: msrp_noform, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: bundle, Block: bundle/catalog_product_price, Template: bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => bundle/catalog_product_price
            [template] => bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: msrp, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => bundle/catalog_product_price
            [template] => bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: simple, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => bundle/catalog_product_price
            [template] => bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml
        )

    [simple] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: grouped, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => bundle/catalog_product_price
            [template] => bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml
        )

    [simple] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [grouped] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: configurable, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => bundle/catalog_product_price
            [template] => bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml
        )

    [simple] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [grouped] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [configurable] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: virtual, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => bundle/catalog_product_price
            [template] => bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml
        )

    [simple] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [grouped] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [configurable] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [virtual] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: bundle, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [simple] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [grouped] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [configurable] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [virtual] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: msrp, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [simple] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [grouped] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [configurable] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [virtual] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: msrp_item, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [simple] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [grouped] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [configurable] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [virtual] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

)

2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Type: msrp_noform, Block: catalog/product_price, Template: catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
2015-12-14T16:07:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [msrp] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [msrp_item] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [msrp_noform] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [bundle] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [simple] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [grouped] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [configurable] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

    [virtual] => Array
        (
            [block] => catalog/product_price
            [template] => catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml
        )

)
```

The interesting thing to note is that the final state of the array has each of the templates that I desire but for some reason they aren't being used.

When I move the price update xml out of `<customer_logged_out>` and into `<default>` the proper template is used, but of course it uses the new template file regardless of user state.

TL;DR: Trying to change the price templates if the user is logged in, doesn't have intended effect when update xml is placed in `<customer_logged_out>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Magento processes customer_logged_out and other event driven handles after the primary handles are utilized.  Based on this, I devised the following solution:

- Create a helper (I called it getPriceTemplate) that accepts an argument
- Move the layout xml into default
- Change each of the templates to use your new helper, passing an arg in with the desired type

Here's the XML:
(Note the helper)

```
<reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
    <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template helper="wholesale/getPriceTemplate" ><arg>bundle</arg></template></action>
    <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>msrp</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template helper="wholesale/getPriceTemplate" ><arg>msrp</arg></template></action>
    <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>msrp_item</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template helper="wholesale/getPriceTemplate" ><arg>msrp_item</arg></template></action>
    <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>msrp_noform</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template helper="wholesale/getPriceTemplate" ><arg>msrp_noform</arg></template></action>
</reference>
```

And here's the helper:

```
<?php 
  protected $_noPriceTemplate = 'catalog/product/view/noprice.phtml';
  protected $_priceTemplateArray = array(
      'bundle' => 'bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml',
      'msrp' => 'catalog/product/price_msrp.phtml',
      'msrp_item' => 'catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml',
      'msrp_noform' => 'catalog/product/price_msrp_noform.phtml',
  );
...
public function getPriceTemplate($type = null) {
  if (!$this->isCustomerAllowed()) return $this->_noPriceTemplate;

  return $this->_priceTemplateArray[$type];

}
```

isCustomerAllowed is a method that checks to see if the current customer should be allowed to see the price and returns a bool.